# can't load css and javascript in rails

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails

I develop application using ruby on rails, I used a template to frontend the application. When I move the project to another computer I get problems that my css can't be load.

When I checked in source view, I get that browser can't be detected that it is an library css. And when I click the css link, it will displayed like this in the browser:

```
/**
*= require front/normalize
*= require front/foundation-ranking
*= require front/ranking
*
**/
```

Please help me to solve this problem. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
/*
*= require normalize
*= require foundation-ranking
*= require ranking
*= require_self
*/
```

Comment: in my css already like that your answer sir abdul malik, but in browser it cant be load and siplayed like what i quote there.

Comment: have you remove ".css" from them ? in your application.css file, make sure you add *= require_self in your application.css

Comment: yeah, i already remove it...
did have minimum requirement rails version or something to make this feature running well?

Comment: i created it like this:

/*
 *= require admin/bootstrap
 *= require admin/bootstrap-responsive
 *= require admin/responsive-tables
*/

Comment: make it /* *= require bootstrap *= require bootstrap-responsive *= require responsive-tables *= require_self */ remove admin and add "*= require_self" in your file, Hope you get this time

Comment: still didnt work..
is there any minimum require version to using this?

Answer (score 0):

Do you have this in your Controller, or if absent, ApplicationController?

```
layout "application"
```

or may be you have

> complied assets folder in your public folder

. So **delete that folder** and try to restart your server. May be this will solve your problem.